# In Firefox 76, how do I enable scrollbar auto-hiding?

Tags: firefox, scrollbar

On Ubuntu 20.04 with a Gnome desktop, how do I instruct Firefox 76 to automatically hide the vertical scrollbar when inactive?

Comment: I think this issue has been around for a long time and it seems there will be no fix https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=549446

Comment: I see, thank you. However, I have always seen scrollbars auto-hide on MacOS. Just out of curiosity: why is it more difficult to implement this feature on Ubuntu than on MacOS?

Comment: @Giorgio I am using macOS right now, and scroll bars in Firefox are visible and do not auto-hide.

Comment: @Dan on the Firefox on my old Mac (High Sierra) they do hide.